# Mapbox Android app - Can raster resources be uploaded through mobile application?

Tags: android, dictionary, mapbox, geotiff, mbtiles

Ive been digging through Mapbox Android documentation and support to find out if it is possible to upload a raster tile from android application. Download / serving is vastly documented, but not upload. In essence, I need to make an app that will allow a user to select a file (raster) from a phone and permanently add it to mapview through the new app.

Does anybody know a short answer? Thx.

Answer (score 0):

In order to upload a raster from your Android phone and permanently add it to the MapView, you *may* be able to use the  [Upload API from Mapbox](https://www.mapbox.com/api-documentation/#uploads).

> The Mapbox Uploads API transforms geographic data into tilesets that
>   can be used with maps and geographic applications.

---

I say *may* because there are only certain types of rasters that the Upload API supports.  See the Upload API link for the full description of the API.

See these links for the Mapboxs description of the potential raster formats that you will have to convert to in order to upload using the Uploads API.

- [GeoTiff](https://www.mapbox.com/help/define-tiff/)
- [MBTiles](https://www.mapbox.com/help/define-mbtiles/)